# XPath for nodes with no twin

Tags: xpath

Here is my document:

```
<records>
  <born name="Alice" year="1970"/>
  <born name="Bob" year="1980"/>
  <died name="Alice" year="2015"/>
</records>
```

I want to select every `born` element that has no corresponding `died` element (i.e., select all people who are still alive). What is the correct XPath expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
//born[not(@name=//died/@name)]
```

Comment: I confirm that it works, but I am confused. It seems to me that //died/@name is a list, so how can @name be equal to it?

Comment: @DanR. `//died/@name` really returns the list of attributes, but predicate `[not(@name=//died/@name)]` works differently - it checks if `@name` of context node is equal to `@name` of *any* `died` node